# Pandas - Turning column of mixed positive / negative numbers to positive

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe I have a column containing numbers, some positive, some negative. Example

```
    Amount
0  -500
1   659
3   -10
4   344
```

I want to turn all numbers Df['Amount'] into positive numbers. I thought about multiplying all numbers with *-1. But though this turns negative numbers positive, and also does the reverse.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you could give `abs()` a try .... [doku](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)

Comment: In addition to Python's `abs()`, Pandas has an `abs()` method as well.  E.g. `df.Amount.abs()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can assign the result back to the original column:

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].abs()
```

Or you can create a new column, instead:

```
df['AbsAmount'] = df['Amount'].abs()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take absolute value

```
d['Amount'].apply(abs)
```

Comment: It appears I still have a lot to learn about the Python Standard Library, thanks!

Comment: @Jasper This is `pandas`, not the standard library. And once you go down the path of numpy/pandas, you'll never find the end of that path :P

Answer (score 2):

abs() is the standard way to get absolute values.